# Is Canine teeth enough evidence to prove that one is a Carnivore?

Tags: human-biology

This question does not assume that *we are meant to be carnivores* in the first place; In fact I have no idea to which category we belong to anyway! There are several posts online indicating that classifying humans as carnivores and pointing to our canine teeth as evidence might be fallacious.

Also, the fact that Hippos, the largest canine teeth of any land mammal, are herbivores indicates there are exceptions to this view. A couple of other animals like the Gorilla are also herbivores with big and sharp canines. I have also read about the lack of cellulace production in humans as a counterargument to the above.

To what category would we fit in to? What evidence is required to support this idea? Do scientists agree upon a common theory?

Comment: We are pretty clearly omnivores.  Our teeth, and more importantly, our actual habits, confirm this.  It is possible for us to live an exclusively herbivorous or carnivorous lifestyle, of course.